# Resizing Images in Android for use in a listview

Tags: android, listview, image-resizing, smooth-scrolling

I have a bunch of "large" 400x400 images that I am pulling from a source on the web and I need to display as 100x100 thumbnails in a ListView on Android. If I simply set the dimensions on the imageview element in xml it is very clear it is only scrunching the images down to 100x100 for 2 reasons:

1) The images don't look resampled
2) When given more than lets say 10 of these images in the list the scrolling becomes unbearably slow

I am not AS worried about #1 but the scrolling needs to stay smooth. So I am wondering, how should I go about resizing/resampling these images and caching them? I've done some googling but I just can't find a good resource for what would be a best practice in this situation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html)  and the [Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) class.  `Options` has an `inSampleSize` value that you can set to scale down an image when you read it in.  You could try something like

```
Options op = new Options();
op.inSampleSize = 4;//You want to scale from 400 to 100
Bitmap thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, op);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and your image will be scaled down to your desired size.